# recyclerview inside scroll view lags while scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, scrollview

What i have are 2 linear layouts (left and right) each consisting of vertically scrolled recyclerView which are scrolling with respect to each other's position.. left one is static with respect to its header... and right one needs to be scrolled horizontally with respect to its header and recyclerview is scrolling vertically.. (header doesnt need to be scrolled vertically). I have already tried nestedscrollview but header is scrolled out of view.
the layout scrolls smoothly while in the case of horizontal but vertically it lags

Here's the code:
**SavingSecondFrag.java** This is the fragment.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_saving_second, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    recyclerViewsInitializations();
    prepareSavingsData();

    recycler_left.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            left_scroll = true;
            right_scroll = false;
            return false;
        }
    });

    recycler_right.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            left_scroll = false;
            right_scroll = true;
            return false;
        }
    });


    recycler_left.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (left_scroll) {
                recycler_right.scrollBy(dx, dy);
                View current = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
            }
        }
    });

    recycler_right.addOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, final int dx, final int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            if (right_scroll) {
                recycler_left.scrollBy(dx, dy);
                Log.e("TAG", dx + " and " + dy);
            }

        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

this is the layout 
Sorry its a bit long..
**fragment_saving_code.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text=""
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:text="Member Name"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_left"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="1200dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Total Saving"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Group"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Personal"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Planned Saving"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Group"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Personal"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="Total Refunded"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="Total Balance"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="Total Interest"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="400dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="400dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Current Saving"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="4">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Group"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Personal"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginRight="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Optional"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Child"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                            android:textSize="16sp" />

                    </LinearLayout>


                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="80dp"
                    android:layout_height="80dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="4dp"
                    android:text="Refund"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_right"
                android:layout_width="1200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[this is the layout screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCP5X.png)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you use a really **complex UI hierarchy** which has **many nested layouts**.
It will slow down your app's performance.

The solution is that you should optimize to make the hierarchy level is as lowest as possible. F*or example, you can use RelativeLayout or ConstraintsLayout instead of many nested LinearLayouts*.

Besides, in your above code, you use a HorizontalView with many of its child views. You can try to replace it with other UI elements with better performance.
For example, you should consider to use TabBar and ViewPager instead.

Comment: HorizontalView in the complex linear layouts are working perfectly... i have no issue while scrolling horizontally.

Comment: You are using many nested layout inside on screen. 
Please check it out for more information. 
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/rendering/optimizing-view-hierarchies.html